# How to set up JAVA_HOME on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, ubuntu

I installed java 1.7 accord to this tutorial [Install Oracle Java 7 in Ubuntu via PPA Repository](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

All looks cool, when I run `java -version` I see:

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)
```

But I need to set JAVA_HOME.
Where is exactly java home on ubuntu?

Here is content of `whereis` and `which` for java:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~$ whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
nazar_art@nazar-desktop:~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

- ***How to set JAVA_HOME on Ubuntu?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDK PPA has been deprecated long time ago due to licensing issues, I don't recommend using it.

Refer to this https://askubuntu.com/a/313182/70270 for installing/configuring Oracle JDK (manual or automated - using [oab-java6](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6)).

> NOTE: oab-java6 download the binary files from OTN and build .deb packages from them. Set up a local APT repository for easier maintenance.

I personally prefer to use a shell script and source it in the shell initialization files (for Ubuntu, use `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`)

For example, `set_java.sh`

```js
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_40
CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH JAVA_HOME CLASSPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/somedir/jdk1.7.0_40
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use alternatives to figure out what /usr/bin/java

```
alternatives --display java
```

And this will reply

```
Current `best' version is /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre/bin/java.
```

Comment: `No command 'alternatives' found, did you mean:
 Command 'galternatives' from package 'galternatives' (universe) alternatives: command not found`